# Prove Inequality (with norm and an inner product)

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

> Prove that for all $f,g\in C[a,b]$ with the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$:
>
> $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y)|^2dxdy\leq ||f||^2||g||^2-|\langle f,g\rangle^2|$$

I have started with $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y)|^2dxdy=\langle f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y),f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y)\rangle\leq$$

By cauchy-schwarz

$$\leq ||f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y)||\cdot||f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y)||$$

Can we continue with

$$||f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y)||\cdot||f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y)||\leq [||f(x)g(y)||+||g(x)f(y)||]\cdot[||f(x)g(y)||+||g(x)f(y)||]?$$

Second thought: to try to prove

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y)|^2dxdy+|\langle f,g\rangle^2|\leq ||f||^2||g||^2$$

Comment: It is not obvious to me that the integral on the left exists. If $f,g\in L^2$, nothing guarantees $f\cdot g \in L^2$. Do the offensive infinities cancel each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be an equality:
\begin{align}
 &\frac{1}{2} \int \int \lvert f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y) \rvert^2 \, dx \, dy \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int \int \left( \lvert f(x) \rvert^2 \lvert g(y) \rvert^2 + \lvert g(x) \rvert^2 \lvert f(y) \rvert^2 - 2\Re(\overline{f(x)g(y)}g(x)f(y)) \right) dx \, dy \\
&= \lVert f \rVert^2 \lVert g \rVert^2 - \Re\left( \int \int \overline{f(x)g(y)}g(x)f(y) \, dx \, dy \right) \\
&= \lVert f \rVert^2 \lVert g \rVert^2 - \Re\left(\left( \int \overline{f(x)}g(x) \, dx \right) \left( \int \overline{g(y)}f(y)\, dy \right)\right) \\
&= \lVert f \rVert^2 \lVert g \rVert^2 - \lvert\langle f,g\rangle \rvert^2
\end{align}
(by expanding, linearity of the integral to bring out the real part, separating the $x$ and $y$ terms and using the definition of the inner-product).

Comment: for $x,y\in \mathbb{C}: |x\pm y|^2=|x|^2\pm 2Re|xy|+|y|^2$ ? why do $R((\int\overline{f(x)}g(x)dx)(\int\overline{g(y)}f(y))dy)=|<f,g>|^2|?$

Comment: The first bracket is $\langle f,g\rangle$, the second is $\langle g,f \rangle$ and $\langle g,f \rangle = \overline{\langle f,g \rangle}$, so it's actually $\Re(\langle f,g \rangle \overline{\langle f,g \rangle}) = \Re \lvert \langle f,g\rangle\rvert^2 = \lvert \langle f,g\rangle\rvert^2 $.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, equality holds:
$\newcommand\inner[2]{\left\langle #1, #2 \right\rangle}$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y)|^2\,dxdy$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y))\overline{(f(x)g(y)-g(x)f(y))}\,dxdy$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}\left(|f(x)g(y)|^2 + |g(x)f(y)|^2 - f(x)\overline{g(x)}\overline{f(y)}g(y) - \overline{f(x)}g(x)f(y)\overline{g(y)}\right)\, dxdy$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} |g(y)|^2 \|f\|^2_2\,dy + \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} |f(y)|^2 \|g\|^2_2\,dy - \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} \overline{f(y)}g(y) \inner{f}{g}\,dy - \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} f(y)\overline{g(y)} \inner{g}{f}\,dy$$
$$= \|f\|^2_2\|g\|^2_2 - \inner{f}{g}\inner{g}{f}$$
$$= \|f\|^2_2\|g\|^2_2 - \left|\inner{f}{g}\right|^2$$